# mergeMap throws 'invalid object where a stream was expected' error in rxjs6

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

After migrating rxjs from v5 to v6 I experience an error when using mergeMap:

```
of('foobar').pipe(
  mergeMap(() => of('baz'))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Error:

```
core.js:1598 ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at Object.push../node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeTo.js.exports.subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:42)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:7)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:132)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:129)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:112)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:103)
    at Observable._subscribe (scalar.js:5)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:176)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:161)
    at MergeMapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call (mergeMap.js:87)
```

`of('baz')` is a stream, right? So why do I get this error?

Comment: Did you do the imports correct? import {of} from 'rxjs'; import {mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: @siva636 ohhh myyy ... it was rxjs/internal/operators .. I switched it to rxjs/operators and it is working now :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to import the operators correctly from

```
rxjs/operators
```

and not

```
rxjs/internal/operators
```

Comment: Thank you very much to save me time!